# asp:ControlParameter access control in different asp:Content block (Master Pages)

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages, sqldatasource

I am setting up an application with two content blocks: FiltersContent and MainContent.

I want to use a Reports.master to style the filters and results into their own blocks. The problem is that when I try to use a  in the  of a , something like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource [...] >          
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="statusFilter" DefaultValue="-1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="startDateFilter" DefaultValue="01/01/1990" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="endDateFilter" DefaultValue="01/01/2070" PropertyName="Text" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It is cannot find the control producing a error like

```
Could not find control 'statusFilter' in ControlParameter ''.
```

As soon as I move the filter controls into the 'Main'

```
  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="MainContent" ... >
```

they work properly.

So my question is: Is it possible to access the controls from a SqlDataSource in a different Content block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the syntax is:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="parentControl$Childcontrol" DefaultValue="-1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
```

Comment: Works great, just a side note, Visual Studio does not know what your attempting to do here so it will display "red" as an error even though perfectly valid and functions correctly.